# How to read from SharedPreference file android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, saving-data

In my MainActivity, I have written some code which I assume creates a file and saves a value in that file.

```
public static final String WHAT_I_WROTE = null;
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();

    //creates new SharedPreference?
    SharedPreferences saver = getSharedPreferences("saved_text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //writes to the preferences file called saved_text?
    SharedPreferences.Editor writer = saver.edit();
    writer.putString(WHAT_I_WROTE, message);
    writer.commit();
}
```

In another activity, I want to be able to read the message and display it but when I try this, it cannot resolve the symbol "saver".

```
String text_for_display = saver.getString(WHAT_I_WROTE);
```

What is the mistake I have made here and how do I correct it to read the saved string?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: why are you using null as key in shared preference?

Comment: WHAT_I_WROTE is null here. Should be changed to a valid string.

Comment: please post the code of other activity where you are getting data from shared preference

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure what null meant. I thought you had to use that as a placeholder when declaring a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another activity you have to again initalize the Shared preference.

```
    SharedPreferences saver = getSharedPreferences("saved_text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String text_for_display = saver.getString(WHAT_I_WROTE),"any_default_value";
```

WHAT_WROTE = "anyText"

Comment: WHAT_I_WROTE is null here. Should be changed to a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the other activity you have:

```
SharedPreferences saver = getSharedPreferences("saved_text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

then read it like this

```
String myValue = saver.getString("saved_text", "default_value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting values in preference is like,

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saved_text", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("WHAT_I_WROTE", message);
 editor.commit();
```

Retrieve the data like,

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("saved_text", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String text_for_display = prefs.getString("WHAT_I_WROTE", null);
```

Comment: it would be confusing that key and the file names are same?

Comment: what?i didnt get you

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put "`context`" before "`getSharedPreferences`" if necessary.